# How to add event listener for console logs in selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following code which works in getting the console log messages when the function is called, the problem is the console log list `driver.get_log('browser')` is not self updating. The console log messages are only gathered in `driver.get_log('browser')` when `printConsoleLog` function is called. How do i add an event listener to the console to automatically display console log messages in Python selenium 4?

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.log import Log
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium import webdriver
import trio
import time

service = Service(executable_path=f"C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/PyCharm/bl/chromedriver.exe")

def wait_seconds(t):
   time.sleep(t)

def printConsoleLogs():
   options = Options()
   options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

   dc = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
   dc["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"browser":"INFO"}

   driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options, desired_capabilities=dc)
   driver.get("http://localhost:9091")

   time.sleep(5)

   for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
        print(entry)

   time.sleep(5)

   for repeat in driver.get_log('browser'):
        print(repeat)

printConsoleLogs()
```

Comment: ANYONE JESUS CREEPERS CHRIST

Comment: Hello anyone can help provide a more detailed documentation on the Bidi protocol?